# Audio playing in Processing not working how I expected

Tags: audio, processing

This particular part of my code will show a red line on the screen whenever I hit a key such as the space bar. It also is supposed to play an audio sound "laser" every time a key is pressed. When I first run my processing code and hit spacebar it plays the sound and displays the red line for as long as I hold down the key (as expected). **However pressing spacebar a second time only results in a red line appearing and no sound playing.** Can someone explain a way to make this work all the time and not just the first time?

```
import ddf.minim.* ;
Minim minim;
AudioPlayer laser;

void setup()
{
  minim = new Minim(this);     
  laser = minim.loadFile("laser.wav");
}

void draw()
{
  if(keyPressed)
  {
    laser.play(); // Laser sound
    stroke(255,0,0); // Red
    line(337,197,1500,197);  // Laser
  }  
  else
  {
    stroke(255,255,255);  // White
    line(337,197,1500,197); // Cover up the laser
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playing sounds with `minim` is like reading a book and you just start reading by `lase.play()` because your sound is short it will play it whole and than its done. If you want to read/play it again you will have to specify start position.

Basic approach is using `laser.rewind()` but you could also use more specific function like `cue(int millis)` for more information read [JavaDoc](http://code.compartmental.net/minim/javadoc/).

Also checking if key is pressed inside `draw()` for playing music is bad approach and I would recommend using keyboard [handlers](http://processing.org/reference/keyPressed_.html).

```java
void draw()
{
    stroke(line);
    line(337,197,1500,197);
}

void keyPressed() {
  laser.play();
  line = color(255, 0, 0);
}

void keyReleased() {
 laser.pause(); //pause when key is released
 laser.rewind();
 line = color(255, 255, 255);
}
```